How can I reuse a volume after updating docker-compose
While updating Ubuntu from 18 to 22 I also switched from docker-compose 1.25 to 2.26.1
When starting my docker container I receive a warning:
WARN[0000] volume "confluence_confluence-postgres2" already exists but was not created by Docker Compose. Use external: true to use an existing volume
If I add the parameter in my docker-compose.yml I get :
external volume "confluence-postgres2" not found
What am I doing wrong ?
I added external: true line only, then I additionally added name: confluence-postgres2
Both did not change the outcome
my docker-compose.yml
services:
  postgres2:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - postgres.env
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5435:5432"
    volumes:
      - confluence-postgres2:/var/lib/postgresql/data


volumes:
  confluence-postgres2:
    external: true
    name: confluence-postgres2

Maybe helpful info
docker volume inspect confluence_confluence-postgres2
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-12-06T10:17:17+01:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/confluence_confluence-postgres2/_data",
        "Name": "confluence_confluence-postgres2",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }

